# How do I insert a twitcker.com "Twitter Ticker" into Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, html

On our secured Google Site I am trying to insert a "Twitter Ticker" using http://twitcker.com. Twitcker creates the code in Javascript, and Google Sites doesn't use Javascript, just HTML. I did find a "converter" site, Google Gadgets Editor https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/tools#GGE to convert Javascript to HTML. But when I attempted to insert it into my Google Site as a Gadget, it doesn't appear, due to (what I think) is an UNSECURED "Twitter Ticker" trying to be inserted into a SECURED Google Site. I did it according the directions I found at (https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets). FYI: when I inserted the "Twitter Ticker" onto my iGoogle page it appears just fine. Help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Twitcker has also a secure HTTPS connection. Did you know that? Maybe try it again with the HTTPS:// prefix in the output code you get.